# wrong usage of BufferedReader

Tags: android, sockets, client, bufferedreader

```
s=new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream())));

        while(s.hasNext()){
             System.out.println("Am intrat in bucla s:");
             longitude=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
             System.out.println("Valoare longitudine:"+longitude);
             latitude=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
             System.out.println(latitude);
```

I'm using the lines above to read some data from a client-server connection;this is the server side.The data are read in scanner s and after that I try to display it,but when I look in logcat I have nothing display but this exception:

> 04-18 00:07:56.138: INFO/global(295):
>   Default buffer size used in
>   BufferedReader constructor. It would
>   be better to be explicit if an 8k-char
>   buffer is required.

Both my client and server are on android!Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is how I read the data,I send latitude and longitude,I assume that is blank spaces delimited,the strange thing is that sometimes is working:

```
        Cursor c=db.getAllData();

           if(c.moveToFirst()) 
             {
              do{

                  longitude=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1));
                  out.println(longitude);
                  latitude=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2));
                  out.println(latitude);

              }while(c.moveToNext());

             }
```

Answer (score 3):

The message seems to be for the `BufferedReader` construct.

First, I do not think you are doing anything "wrong", since you are saying that the code works as expected and the message is "INFO", not "ERROR" or even "WARNING".

Second, if you look at the `BufferedReader` constructor, you will see:

> BufferedReader(Reader in, int size)
>   Constructs a new BufferedReader, providing in with size characters of buffer.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Use that constructor instead and you should not see that message.

BTW, the `logcat` is full of output, some lines are more relevant than others.

---

Use `Log.d` instead of `System.out.println()`. Regarding `System.out`: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

> Viewing stdout and stderr
>
> By default, the Android system sends
>   stdout and stderr (System.out and
>   System.err) output to /dev/null. In
>   processes that run the Dalvik VM, you
>   can have the system write a copy of
>   the output to the log file. In this
>   case, the system writes the messages
>   to the log using the log tags stdout
>   and stderr, both with priority I.
>
> To route the output in this way, you
>   stop a running emulator/device
>   instance and then use the shell
>   command setprop to enable the
>   redirection of output. Here's how you
>   do it:
>
> $ adb shell stop $ adb shell setprop
>   log.redirect-stdio true $ adb shell
>   start
>
> The system retains this setting until
>   you terminate the emulator/device
>   instance. To use the setting as a
>   default on the emulator/device
>   instance, you can add an entry to
>   /data/local.prop on the device.

Comment: I wanna see my data displayed,the message is not a problem:)))..Thank u:)

Comment: And no,the code does not work at expected-it doesn't display any data in the logcat!!!I said it works fine...no it doesn't otherwise I wouldn't be here praying for someone to come and tell me what I do wrong:)

Answer (score 1):

Is your data white-space delimited? If not, you will need to specify delimiter for your Scanner.

Do you have some exception handling code you are not showing... e.g. hiding a NumberFormatException if parseInt failed?

While you debug this issue (unless you can attach a debugger), you could log messages at points like when you accept new client connection and when you enter and exit your worker thread. This might help you see whether you are getting as far as scanning the data when you think you are receiving.

Comment: I've edited my question with how I send the data and is blank space delimited:)

Comment: Look  here,is my entire code here,in WorkerRunnable I read this data:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701674/how-to-verify-multithreading-server-in-android

Comment: Did u look at the code?Well,I've used messages and I used one exactly before scanning the data ...and it was displayed in the logcatr,but the data itself isn't displayed...and I really don't know what is wrong and I don't have anyone to help me:)...Thx