# generate byte array from StringBuffer.toString

Tags: java, android

What I'm trying to do is to generate a byte array from a url.

```
byte[] data = WebServiceClient.download(url);
```

The `url` returns json

```
public static byte[] download(String url) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
        int code = status.getStatusCode();
        switch (code) {
            case 200:
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                is.close();

                sContent = sb.toString();

                break;       
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sContent.getBytes();
}
```

This `data` is used as a parameter for `String`

```
String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
```

for some reason, I get this error

```
I/global  (  631): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
```

I think something there must be missing here `sContent = sb.toString();` or here `return sContent.getBytes();` but I'm not sure though.

Comment: Is this android (Dalvik VM)?

Comment: Does the error go away if you do `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8192);` ?

Comment: I'd suggest you use the BufferedInputStream to read 4 or 8 kilo bytes chunk of data, rather than dealing with character data and messing with Character sets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wrong usage of BufferedReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702787/wrong-usage-of-bufferedreader)

Comment: BTW, you can use a StringBuilder instead a StringBuffer: in a local variable, synchronous operations are not needed

Comment: @Andreas yes this is android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Consider using Apache [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to read the bytes from `InputStream`

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
try {
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
}finally{
    is.close();
}
```

Currently you're unnecessarily converting the bytes to characters and back.

**2.** Avoid using `String.getBytes()` without passing the charset as a parameter. Instead use

```
String s = ...;
s.getBytes("utf-8")
```

---

As a whole I'd rewrite you're method like this:

```
public static byte[] download(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
    int code = status.getStatusCode();
    if(code != 200) {
        throw new IOException(code+" response received.");
    }
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    try {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    }finally{
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is.close());
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably also use `IOUtils.closeQuietly()`.